# org.hibernate.InvalidMappingException:Could not parse mapping document from resource com/lara/Person.hbm.xml

Tags: hibernate, configuration

```
Exception in thread "main" org.hibernate.InvalidMappingException: Could not parse mapping document from resource com/lara/Person.hbm.xml
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.addResource(Configuration.java:616)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.parseMappingElement(Configuration.java:1635)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.parseSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1603)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.doConfigure(Configuration.java:1582)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.doConfigure(Configuration.java:1556)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.configure(Configuration.java:1476)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.configure(Configuration.java:1462)
    at com.lara.Manager.main(Manager.java:15)
Caused by: org.hibernate.InvalidMappingException: Could not parse mapping document from invalid mapping
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.addInputStream(Configuration.java:549)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.addResource(Configuration.java:613)
    ... 7 more
Caused by: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 7; columnNumber: 39; Document root element "hibernate-mapping", must match DOCTYPE root "hibernate-configuration".
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.createSAXParseException(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.error(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.dtd.XMLDTDValidator.rootElementSpecified(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.dtd.XMLDTDValidator.handleStartElement(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.dtd.XMLDTDValidator.startElement(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.scanStartElement(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl$NSContentDriver.scanRootElementHook(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl$FragmentContentDriver.next(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl$PrologDriver.next(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl.next(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.next(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanDocument(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XMLParser.parse(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.parse(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.SAXParserImpl$JAXPSAXParser.parse(Unknown Source)
    at org.dom4j.io.SAXReader.read(SAXReader.java:465)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.addInputStream(Configuration.java:546)
    ... 8 more
```

## hibernate.cfg.xml

```
        <?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
       <!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC
        "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN"
        "http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">
        <hibernate-configuration>

    <session-factory>

        <!-- Database connection settings -->
        <property name="connection.driver_class">oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver</property>
        <property name="connection.url">jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:XE</property>
        <property name="connection.username">system</property>
        <property name="connection.password">system</property>

        <!-- JDBC connection pool (use the built-in) -->
        <property name="connection.pool_size">2</property>

        <!-- SQL dialect -->
        <property name="dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.OracleDialect</property>

        <!-- Enable Hibernate's current session context -->
        <property name="current_session_context_class">org.hibernate.context.ManagedSessionContext</property>

        <!-- Disable the second-level cache  -->
        <property name="cache.provider_class">org.hibernate.cache.NoCacheProvider</property>

        <!-- Echo all executed SQL to stdout -->
        <property name="show_sql">true</property>

        <!-- Drop and re-create the database schema on startup -->
        <property name="hbm2ddl.auto">create</property>


        <mapping resource="com/lara/Person.hbm.xml"/>

    </session-factory>

     </hibernate-configuration>




Person.hbm.xml
==============
        <?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
        <!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC
        "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN"
        "http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">


        <hibernate-mapping package="com.lara">

    <class name="Person" table="PERSON">
        <id name="id" column="PERSON_ID">
            <generator class="native" />
        </id>
        <property name="age"/>
        <property name="firstname"/>
        <property name="lastname"/>

    </class>

        </hibernate-mapping>


Person.java
=============
        package com.lara;

        public class Person {
    private int id;
    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;
    private int age;

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getFirstName() {
        return firstName;
    }

    public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
    }

    public String getLastName() {
        return lastName;
    }

    public void setLastName(String lastName) {
        this.lastName = lastName;
    }

    public int getAge() {
        return age;
    }

    public void setAge(int age) {
        this.age = age;
    }

      }

Manager.java
=============
        package com.lara;

        import org.hibernate.Session;
        import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
        import org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration;

        public class Manager {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Person p1 = new Person();
        p1.setFirstName("abc");
        p1.setLastName("xyz");
        p1.setAge(22);

        Configuration c1 = new Configuration().configure();

        SessionFactory sf = c1.buildSessionFactory();
        Session s1 = sf.openSession();

        s1.beginTransaction();
        s1.save(p1);
        s1.getTransaction().commit();

        s1.flush();
        s1.close();
        System.out.println("done");
     }
       }
```

Answer (score 6):

The error message says (buried in a big stack trace):

```
Document root element "hibernate-mapping", must match DOCTYPE root "hibernate-configuration"
```

This is because in your Person.hbm.xml file, you have

```
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC
"-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN"
"http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">
```

where you should probably have

```
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-mapping PUBLIC
"-//Hibernate/Hibernate Mapping DTD 3.0//EN"
"http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-mapping-3.0.dtd">
```

This DOCTYPE has to match the root tag.

Answer (score 4):

it's simple

1.create constructor

```
public Person(){}
```

this is main thing in hibernate. it will map the object through this constructor(using Java Reflection Concept)

2.Understand the dtd.
  there are two types of dtd available mapping dtd and configuration dtd

Mapping-dtd is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-mapping PUBLIC
        "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Mapping DTD 3.0//EN"
        "http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-mapping-3.0.dtd">
```

configuration dtd is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC
        "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN"
        "http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">
```

hibernate.cfg.xml is configuration file  and Person.hbm.xml is Mapping File 
so change the dtd in Person.hbm.xml

it will run.

Answer (score 1):

*InvalidmappingException arise in some condition please to read carefully*

1. we will use 
   instead of id tag we use then this exception occur definitely.
2. In Pojo class you declare data member like "name" in database u declare "name" ok then 
   in mapping file u write just  in brief terms we can say that 
   like whatever u declare in id tag name attribute value its corresponding there is no 
   data member in pojo class then only one error arise **InvalidMappingException .**
3. **SQLGrammarException** arise when  orthis column name not exact match to corresponding database filed.

Answer (score 0):

I also got this error message. But in my case the class name was wrong. Add correct package and class name according to bellow example.

```
<class name="com.project.Question" table="question">
```