# Duplicate import: Employee -> Employee org.hibernate.InvalidMappingException: Could not parse mapping document from resource Employee.hbm.xml

Tags: java

I am new t hibernate
When I am trying to execute below code I am getting below Exception:

org.hibernate.InvalidMappingException: Could not parse mapping document from resource Employee.hbm.xml

Here is my code:

Configuration:

```
    <hibernate-configuration> 
    <session-factory> 
    <property name="hibernate.dialect"> 
    org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect 
    </property> 
    <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class"> 
    com.mysql.jdbc.Driver 
    </property> 

    <property name="hibernate.connection.url"> 
    jdbc:mysql://localhost/hibernatetest 
    </property> 
    <property name="hibernate.connection.username"> 
    root 
    </property> 
    <property name="hibernate.connection.password"> 
    root 
    </property> 

    <!-- List of XML mapping files --> 
    <mapping resource="Employee.hbm.xml"/> 

    </session-factory> 
    </hibernate-configuration>
```

Source:

```
    package com.practice.HBtest; 

public class Employee {

    private int id;
    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;
    private Integer salary;

    public Employee() {}

    public Employee(String fname, String lname, int salary) {
        this.firstName = fname;
        this.lastName = lname;
        this.salary = salary;
    }

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getFirstName() {
        return firstName;
    }

    public void setFirstName(String first_name) {
        this.firstName = first_name;
    }

    public String getLastName() {
        return lastName;
    }

    public void setLastName(String last_name) {
        this.lastName = last_name;
    }

    public int getSalary() {
        return salary;
    }

    public void setSalary(int salary) {
        this.salary = salary;
    }
}
```

Mapping:

```
<hibernate-mapping> 
<class name="Employee" table="EMPLOYEE"> 
<id name="id" type="int" column="id"> 
<generator class="native"/> 
</id> 

<property name="firstname" column="first_name" type="String"/> 
<property name="lastname" column="last_name" type="String"/> 
<property name="salary" column="salary" type="int"/>    
</class> 
</hibernate-mapping>
```

Source extract:

```
import org.hibernate.HibernateException;
import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.hibernate.Session;
import org.hibernate.Transaction;
import org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration;
import org.hibernate.service.ServiceRegistry;

public class EmployeeRecordManager {

    private static SessionFactory sessionFactory;
    private static ServiceRegistry serviceRegistry;
    private Session session;

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        EmployeeRecordManager erm = new EmployeeRecordManager();

        try {
            Configuration cfg = new Configuration().addResource("Employee.hbm.xml");
            SessionFactory sessionFactory = cfg.configure().buildSessionFactory(serviceRegistry);

        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e);
        }
        Integer empID1 = erm.addEmployee("Amruta", "Ali", 1000);
        Integer empID2 = erm.addEmployee("Ruchi", "Das", 5000);
        Integer empID3 = erm.addEmployee("Mitul", "Paul", 10000);

        System.out.println(erm);

    }

    public Integer addEmployee(String fname, String lname, int salary) {
        Session session = sessionFactory.openSession();
        Transaction tx = null;
        Integer empID = null;
        try {
            tx = session.beginTransaction();
            Employee employee = new Employee(fname, lname, salary);
            empID = (Integer) session.save(employee);
            tx.commit();
        } catch (HibernateException e) {
            if (tx != null)
                tx.rollback();
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            session.close();
        }
        return empID;
    }

}







   Nov 7, 2012 5:36:15 PM org.hibernate.annotations.common.Version <clinit>
INFO: HCANN000001: Hibernate Commons Annotations {4.0.1.Final}
Nov 7, 2012 5:36:15 PM org.hibernate.Version logVersion
INFO: HHH000412: Hibernate Core {4.1.8.Final}
Nov 7, 2012 5:36:15 PM org.hibernate.cfg.Environment <clinit>
INFO: HHH000206: hibernate.properties not found
Nov 7, 2012 5:36:15 PM org.hibernate.cfg.Environment buildBytecodeProvider
INFO: HHH000021: Bytecode provider name : javassist
Nov 7, 2012 5:36:15 PM org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration addResource
INFO: HHH000221: Reading mappings from resource: Employee.hbm.xml
Nov 7, 2012 5:36:15 PM org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration configure
INFO: HHH000043: Configuring from resource: /hibernate.cfg.xml
Nov 7, 2012 5:36:15 PM org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration getConfigurationInputStream
INFO: HHH000040: Configuration resource: /hibernate.cfg.xml
Nov 7, 2012 5:36:15 PM org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration addResource
INFO: HHH000221: Reading mappings from resource: Employee.hbm.xml
Nov 7, 2012 5:36:15 PM org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration doConfigure
INFO: HHH000041: Configured SessionFactory: null
Nov 7, 2012 5:36:15 PM org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration$MappingsImpl addImport
INFO: HHH000071: Duplicate import: Employee -> Employee
org.hibernate.InvalidMappingException: Could not parse mapping document from resource Employee.hbm.xml
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration$MetadataSourceQueue.processHbmXml(Configuration.java:3417)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration$MetadataSourceQueue.processHbmXmlQueue(Configuration.java:3406)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration$MetadataSourceQueue.processMetadata(Configuration.java:3394)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.secondPassCompile(Configuration.java:1341)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1737)
    at com.practice.HBtest.EmployeeRecordManager.main(EmployeeRecordManager.java:24)
Caused by: org.hibernate.DuplicateMappingException: Duplicate class/entity mapping Employee
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration$MappingsImpl.addClass(Configuration.java:2582)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.HbmBinder.bindRoot(HbmBinder.java:174)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration$MetadataSourceQueue.processHbmXml(Configuration.java:3414)
    ... 5 more
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.practice.HBtest.EmployeeRecordManager.addEmployee(EmployeeRecordManager.java:39)
    at com.practice.HBtest.EmployeeRecordManager.main(EmployeeRecordManager.java:30)
org.hibernate.InvalidMappingException: Could not parse mapping document from resource Employee.hbm.xml
After Adding the code mentioned by you was getting below Exception:


  Nov 7, 2012 6:48:24 PM org.hibernate.annotations.common.Version <clinit>
INFO: HCANN000001: Hibernate Commons Annotations {4.0.1.Final}
Nov 7, 2012 6:48:24 PM org.hibernate.Version logVersion
INFO: HHH000412: Hibernate Core {4.1.8.Final}
Nov 7, 2012 6:48:24 PM org.hibernate.cfg.Environment <clinit>
INFO: HHH000206: hibernate.properties not found
Nov 7, 2012 6:48:24 PM org.hibernate.cfg.Environment buildBytecodeProvider
INFO: HHH000021: Bytecode provider name : javassist
Nov 7, 2012 6:48:24 PM org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration configure
INFO: HHH000043: Configuring from resource: hibernate.cfg.xml
Nov 7, 2012 6:48:24 PM org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration getConfigurationInputStream
INFO: HHH000040: Configuration resource: hibernate.cfg.xml
Nov 7, 2012 6:48:24 PM org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration addResource
INFO: HHH000221: Reading mappings from resource: Employee.hbm.xml
Nov 7, 2012 6:48:24 PM org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration doConfigure
INFO: HHH000041: Configured SessionFactory: null
Nov 7, 2012 6:48:24 PM org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration configure
INFO: HHH000043: Configuring from resource: /hibernate.cfg.xml
Nov 7, 2012 6:48:24 PM org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration getConfigurationInputStream
INFO: HHH000040: Configuration resource: /hibernate.cfg.xml
Nov 7, 2012 6:48:24 PM org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration addResource
INFO: HHH000221: Reading mappings from resource: Employee.hbm.xml
Nov 7, 2012 6:48:24 PM org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration doConfigure
INFO: HHH000041: Configured SessionFactory: null
Nov 7, 2012 6:48:24 PM org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration$MappingsImpl addImport
INFO: HHH000071: Duplicate import: Employee -> Employee
org.hibernate.InvalidMappingException: Could not parse mapping document from resource Employee.hbm.xml
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration$MetadataSourceQueue.processHbmXml(Configuration.java:3417)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration$MetadataSourceQueue.processHbmXmlQueue(Configuration.java:3406)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration$MetadataSourceQueue.processMetadata(Configuration.java:3394)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.secondPassCompile(Configuration.java:1341)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1737)
    at com.practice.HBtest.EmployeeRecordManager.main(EmployeeRecordManager.java:24)
Caused by: org.hibernate.DuplicateMappingException: Duplicate class/entity mapping Employee
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration$MappingsImpl.addClass(Configuration.java:2582)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.HbmBinder.bindRoot(HbmBinder.java:174)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration$MetadataSourceQueue.processHbmXml(Configuration.java:3414)
    ... 5 more
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.practice.HBtest.EmployeeRecordManager.addEmployee(EmployeeRecordManager.java:39)
    at com.practice.HBtest.EmployeeRecordManager.main(EmployeeRecordManager.java:30)
org.hibernate.InvalidMappingException: Could not parse mapping document from resource Employee.hbm.xml
```

Comment: post your `Employee.hbm.xml` code

Comment: Some problem in your `Employee.hbm.xml` or its path.

Comment: [Duplicated](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12010056/org-hibernate-invalidmappingexceptioncould-not-parse-mapping-document-from-reso) refer the link make changes in confgiuration

Comment: Employee.hbm.xml is a configuration file

Answer (score 3):

There is a casing discrepancy between your hbm.xml property names :

```
<property name="firstname" column="first_name" type="String"/> 
<property name="lastname" column="last_name" type="String"/> 
<property name="salary" column="salary" type="int"/>
```

and the actual member fields in your class:

```
private String first**N**ame; 
private String last**N**ame; 
private Integer salary;
```

and more importantly your getters and setters in your class also have camelcasing, while hibernate will be looking for 
`getFirstname()`, `setFirstname()`, ...

Comment: I have done the changes as mentioned still it's giving me same exception.

Comment: Also in continuation with the Exception it says:Exception in thread main: "java.lang.NullPointerException"

Answer (score 1):

Use [JPA annotations](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/tutorial/doc/bnbpz.html) instead of mess XML

Answer (score 0):

Could you paste your entire stack trace?  It s kind of hard to debug this without an entire stack trace as therea are alot of things that can go wrong at the juncture where you load the hibernate configuration.

It might have to do with the way you define your configuration & build up your connectivity.  What i usually do is:

- load the config from the main hibernate config file
  configuration = new Configuration().configure("hibernate.cfg.xml");
- build the session factory from the configuration you loaded
  sessionFactory = configuration.buildSessionFactory();

There is no reason to explicitly add the hbm.xml resource (as you have defined that resource already in your main configuration file, nor to use a service registry parameter when building a session factory ...

Also your id mapping might need to put the DB column in a seperate tag, like :

```
<id name="id" type="int">
            <column name="id" scale="0" />
            <generator class="native" />
</id>
```

Comment: When i have tried your suggestion for load the config from the main hibernate config file configuration = new Configuration().configure("hibernate.cfg.xml"); it throws an Exception

Comment: Hey I was able to fix my issue.There was one jar missing added that jar as well added the correct port for mysql which has fixed the issue. :)

Answer (score 0):

I was able to fix the issue.
1. Added mysql connector jar
2.Added correct port for that
3.Used the below configuration:

```
Configuration configuration = new Configuration();
            configuration.configure();
            serviceRegistry = new ServiceRegistryBuilder().applySettings(configuration.getProperties()).buildServiceRegistry();        
            sessionFactory = configuration.buildSessionFactory(serviceRegistry);
```

Thanks
Everyone who so ever has contributed

Answer (score 0):

I have been through this issue; found following solutions

- Clean your server build directory i.e. clean eclipse project and make
  sure same (dulpicate)

***.hbm*** file should not to be there.

- If your POJO is outside in project; then keep it into to package and define package in ***.hbm*** file
- You must have all the fields available with its getter and setter in POJO w.r.t hbm file.
- Make sure fields are case sensitive as mentioned above by "Filip".
- Check the jar files are available