# org.hibernate.InvalidMappingException: Could not parse mapping document from resource --> parseSessionFactory

Tags: java, hibernate

Recently I upgrade the weblogic server from 11g to 12.2.1.3 and redeploy the web application. When run the application, it throws below exception. It is something wrong in session. I tried to google in the web but not luck as it is creating session problem. I believe no problem in hiberate config or mapping xml file as I tried according to the google search (e.g. `https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12010056/org-hibernate-invalidmappingexceptioncould-not-parse-mapping-document-from-reso`) but still same problem.

```
%%%% Error Creating SessionFactory %%%%
org.hibernate.InvalidMappingException: Could not parse mapping document from resource com/xxxx/hibernate/SSmsPromotion.hbm.xml
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.addResource(Configuration.java:588)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.parseMappingElement(Configuration.java:1606)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.parseSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1574)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.doConfigure(Configuration.java:1553)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.doConfigure(Configuration.java:1527)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.configure(Configuration.java:1447)
    at com.xxxx.hibernate.HibernateSessionFactory.rebuildSessionFactory(HibernateSessionFactory.java:69)
    at com.xxxx.hibernate.HibernateSessionFactory.getSession(HibernateSessionFactory.java:53)
    at com.xxxx.onlineapplications.manager.SBranchManager.getSBranchCatList(SBranchManager.java:19)

public class SBranchManager{
    ...........
    public ArrayList getSBranchCatList(String langId, String appType) throws Exception{
        ArrayList branchCatList = new ArrayList();
        Session session = HibernateSessionFactory.getSession();  <--- Line 19
    ................

    }
}
public class HibernateSessionFactory {

    private static String CONFIG_FILE_LOCATION = "/hibernate.cfg.xml";
    private static final ThreadLocal threadLocal = new ThreadLocal();
    private  static Configuration configuration = new Configuration();    
    private static org.hibernate.SessionFactory sessionFactory;
    private static String configFile = CONFIG_FILE_LOCATION;

    public static Session getSession() throws HibernateException {
        Session session = (Session) threadLocal.get();

        if (session == null || !session.isOpen()) {
            if (sessionFactory == null) {
                rebuildSessionFactory();  <---- Line 53
            }
            session = (sessionFactory != null) ? sessionFactory.openSession()
                    : null;
            threadLocal.set(session);
        }

        return session;
    }


    public static void rebuildSessionFactory() {
        try {
            configuration.configure(configFile);  <--- Line 69
            sessionFactory = configuration.buildSessionFactory(); 
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.err
                    .println("%%%% Error Creating SessionFactory %%%%");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I found out that the order-by in xml causing this cause. Solved

Answer (score 0):

It is solved by removing the below line in weblogic.xml

```
<!--    <container-descriptor>
        <prefer-web-inf-classes>true</prefer-web-inf-classes>
    </container-descriptor> -->
```